# Backing up each and every resources in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am exploring backing up our AWS services configuration to a backup disk or source control.

Only configs. eg -iam policies, users, roles, lambdas,route53 configs,cognito configs,vpn configs,route tables, security groups etc....

We have a tactical account where we have created some resources on adhoc basis and now we have a new official account setup via cloud formation.

Also in near future planning to migrate tactical account resources to new account either manually or using backup configs.

Looked at AWS CLI, but it is time consuming. Any script which crawls through AWS and backup the  resources?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way is not to 'backup' resources. Rather, it is to initially create those resources in a reproducible manner.

For example, creating resources via an **AWS CloudFormation template** allows the same resources to be deployed in a different region or account. Only the data itself, such as the information stored in a database, would need a 'backup'. Everything else could simply be redeployed.

There is a poorly-maintained service called [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) that attempts to create CloudFormation templates from existing resources, but it only supports limited services and still requires careful editing of the resulting templates before they can be deployed in other locations (due to cross-references to existing resources).

There is also the relatively recent ability to [Import Existing Resources into a CloudFormation Stack | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/), but it requires that the template already includes the resource definition. The existing resources are simply matched to that definition rather than being recreated.

So, you now have the choice to 'correctly' deploy resources in your new account (involves work), or just manually recreate the ad-hoc resources that already exist (pushes the real work to the future). Hence the term [Technical debt - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Cloudformer. I am aware of properly creating resources  using cloud formation. I am trying to reduce the technical debt on our team.